# Saving each element of a list in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, savechanges

I have an `@Html.Hidden("")` input form in `View` that sends to controller multiple int values separated by comma and I want to save each value along with `URL` id.

How I retrieve from View my list of elements:

```
var keywordsID = Request.Form["values"].Split(',').ToList();
```

How I am trying to save in db:

```
foreach (var item in keywordsID) 
{
    var jobtags = new JobTags
    {
         JobID = job.ID.ToString(),
         TagID = item. /*SOMETHING*/
    };

    db.JobTags.Add(jobtags);
}
```

Values are fine when I checked them with breakpoints they are like: "1" "2" etc. I don't know how to fetch each `TagID` with the elements from my list. Any tips please?

***EDIT Solution:***

I added a new line that has nothing to do with question but it was needed in order for insert to work properly:

```
var currentJobID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["DetailsURL"]);/*I retrieve the URL ID here (JobID)*/
```

And `foreach` statement:

```
foreach (var item in keywordsID) 
{
    var jobtags = new JobTags
    {
        JobID = currentJobID,
        TagID = item /*Here isn't any other "SOMETHING", 
                     I just left item how it is and I have my records inserted */
    };

    db.JobTags.Add(jobtags);
 }
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: How is an element from your list  associated to the tagId? Does it match with 'value' of tagId? 'Name' of tagId?...

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean. I use an autocomplete script with multiple values in a textbox and I extract the ID of each TagName in a @Html.Hidden and pass them back to controller to save them along with the jobID. I just want each value from keywordsID list to be saved in TagID field in another table.

Comment: More simplified explaining: I have a `var myList = new List<Int32>{ 1, 2, 3};` and I want to save each element of myList to TagID along with JobID. They are not related because there isn't any model associated with JobTags. I can't do things like this?

Comment: So if the value of keywordsID is {"1", "2"}, you want the TagID  to be set to 1 (integer type) for the first jobTags. Right?

Comment: Yea, as long there are values in keywordsID I want to insert them with the JobID. But that keywordsID list have nothing to do with JobTags model, and I am still thinking how to insert this numbers there from a random list.

Comment: That's why I asked you my first question. I think you are answering your own question now. You need to create another table to create this association. Your table should have ID and Values.

Comment: **1**, **2**, **3** in `myList = new List<Int32>{ 1, 2, 3 }` are `TagID`s, right?

Comment: Yea its working now, I figured how stupid I am sometimes. There are actually no problems with the code, I was just over thinking this, and @Feryal made me think much simplier. I will edit my question with the fuctional code